# Why doesn't this IN (inner query) query return any results?

Tags: mysql

The following query returns a bunch of pairs of duplicate solutions:

```
SELECT *
FROM solutions s1, solutions s2
WHERE s2.ID <> s1.ID
AND s2.solution = s1.solution
```

I'm looking simply for the number of duplicate solutions, so that won't work *(eg. if there are `n` duplicates, it returns `n!` rows)*.

The following query *should* work to return only those solutions which are duplicated, but instead **it returns 0 results**:

```
SELECT *
FROM solutions s1
WHERE s1.ID IN
(
   SELECT s2.ID
   FROM solutions s2
   WHERE s2.ID <> s1.ID
   AND s2.solution = s1.solution
)
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why.  Are there restrictions on inner-queries in MySQL that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner query does not return any rows because it's impossible to find `s1.ID IN()` a list selected from IDs that do not match `s1.ID`s.

Comment: Re Edit:  Of course `s1.ID` isn't going to be in a list that doesn't contain `s1.ID` - that is possibly the dumbest mistake I have ever made.  Thank you for pointing that out, I will accept when it allows me to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COUNT()` to determine this quite easily

```
SELECT solution, COUNT(id) AS `count`
FROM solutions
GROUP BY solution
HAVING `count` > 1
```

To answer your question.  You can't reference the outer table `s1` in the inner query.

Comment: Wouldn't the inability to reference a relation result in an error? (I use SQL Server and expect as much.)

Comment: I assume you mean `solution` rather than `id`.  But, this answer is tangential to my question...

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft You are showing `solutions` as your table name and `id` as these field on which you are looking for dupes in your example. I did provide information on why your subselect is not working. Though I added this shortly after my initial answer.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Ah yes you are correct, I misread you query at first.